# Disable registration and login and buying with money

Tags: checkout, email, login

Can I disable magento's registration and login features, so it could work without checkouts. If customer wants to buy a product, he must recieve an email from magento with bank credinationals of the magento's shop owner. Is it possible?

Comment: It's certainly possible to remove login and registration features.   I'm not sure I follow what you mean by receiving an email with bank credentials.  Could you please describe this in a bit more detail?

Comment: Hi! Paying for product using bank transfers. All data on where to pay comes in the email

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can completely ignore the Magento login/checkout process.

([*Completely* Disabling Frontend Customer Registration](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97448/completely-disabling-frontend-customer-registration/97496#97496))

Here is what I would suggest in your case:

1. Allow your customer to add to cart
2. When customer are in cart page, make a button saying 'Complete Your Order'
3. When clicked on the button take them to a page (or open in popup) where they can fill up form
4. On submission, along with the cart items (which you can get using checkout/session) send an email to either parties.

Hope this makes some sense.