# *Completely* Disabling Frontend Customer Registration

Tags: magento-1.9, register

So I have read a few threads which all go into detail of removing the create account login button, hiding the content, and even creating a mini extension to remove such activity (http://importantmagento.blogspot.com/2012/06/how-to-disable-user-registration-in_22.html)

I have done all of these, however still adding `customer/account/create/` to the end of the webstore still persists with a create account page. Any ideas what I can do here? I have a webstore in which we manually create each account, however it appears someone has found the loophole and persists in creating an account. Thanks!

Comment: Try disabling module output for Mage_Customer

Comment: Could also use an .htaccess URL rewrite to make it loop back to homepage.

Comment: That seems to remove all customer interaction, such as now there is no ability to log in

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply use event `controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_create` to disable registration.

**Register the event-observer**

```
<events>
    <controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_create>
        <observers>
            <magepsycho_customer_controller_action_predispatch>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>magepsycho_customer/observer</class>
                <method>controllerActionPredispatchCustomerAccountCreate</method>
            </magepsycho_customer_controller_action_predispatch>
        </observers>
    </controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_create>
</events>
```

**Implement the Observer Model**

```
<?php

/**
 * @category   MagePsycho
 * @package    MagePsycho_Customer
 * @author     magepsycho@gmail.com
 * @website    http://www.magepsycho.com
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */
class MagePsycho_Customer_Model_Observer
{
    public function controllerActionPredispatchCustomerAccountCreate(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {   
        Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login'))->sendResponse();
        exit();
    }
}
```

That's all.
Don't forget to remove Register links from wherever it's visible :)

Comment: `<method>controllerActionPredispatch</method>` don't match the function name in `Observer.php`.

Comment: Thanks @MagePsycho ! I packaged this as a small Magento module: https://github.com/borasocom-team/Magento-PreventUsersRegistration pull requests are most welcome :-)

Comment: That's not all, there should also be a redirect on the `customer/account/createPost` endpoint.

Answer (score 6):

You can add custom URL Rewrite Rules in admin panel as well. check below example to redirect customer/account/create to customer/account/login

[image: URL Rewrite Rules]

Comment: Thank you, this is a lot easier indeed. I found URL Rewrite rules under the catologue menu and had to change the type to Custom before seeing your beautiful screenshot. You can put a dot (.) in the target Path to redirect to the home page. Then I removed all login forms in the template.